# Heroku PostgreSQL: Warning: addons: is not a heroku command

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask

I have found the same questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144837/addonsadd-is-not-a-heroku-command), but the answer did not solve my problem.

**Problem:**
I have a local flask app running with working PostgreSQL database. In [this](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploying-your-flask-application-to-heroku-c99050bce8f9) article I found a good description how to deploy it to Heroku but the following step causes my problem:

```
heroku addons: add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

**Result is:**

```
Warning: addons: is not a heroku command.
Did you mean addons? [y/n]:
```

**After "y":**

```
Error: Unexpected arguments: add, heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
See more help with --help
```

Heroku works per se on my Win machine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```